# Accessing values using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am working on an XML format that is generated automatically by another application, and I want to traverse the XML using Linq to XML, but I'm not sure how to get the values I need.

Here is a snippet of the XML:

```
<dict>
<key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>    
<key>Tracks</key>
<dict>
    <key>3620</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>3620</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Ran</string>
        <key>Age</key><integer>22</integer>         
    </dict>
    <key>3622</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Track ID</key><integer>3622</integer>
        <key>Name</key><string>Jardine</string>
        <key>Age</key><integer>24</integer>         
    </dict>
```

as you can see, `dict` is repeated internally, and the key and values are separated by individual nodes. I need to get `dict` nodes where their key `age` is greater than a value (or basically, I need to filter by a value under the `dict`)

Here's what I have got so far to get all `Age` values as a list:

```
        var ran = x.Root.Elements("dict")
                    .Elements("dict")
                    .Elements("dict")
                    .Select(r =>
                        r.Descendants("key")
                        .Where(w => w.Value == "Age")
                        .Select(s => (XElement)
                            s.NextNode
                            )
                    ).ToList();
```

Since the `Key`'s actual value is stored as a sibling node, I access those using `NextNode`.

However, that's where the problem is. How do I filter those `XElements` in the variable `ran` according to a condition, such as greater than a value?

I tried `ran.Any` and `ran.Select` but I'm not sure which lambda expression to use. Or should I append my filter in my original `ran` query?

Comment: That's a pretty bad XML format. When two values belong together, it shouldn't be indicated just by them being next to each other.

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML format is here to stay (since it's from iTunes XML library actually) and cannot change it.

Instead, I transformed the XML from its current form, using an XSL file, to a friendlier XML format that can be read by `XElement` in .NET. Then it's a simple Linq to XML query to filter out the items I need.

I got the XSL here http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2004/06/14/convert-your-itunes-library-xml-into-html.aspx if anyone needs it. It transforms the XML to an HTML format, but I modified the XSL so my app can properly consume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ElementsAfterSelf.First()` you can move on to the next XElement. This code is making a lot of assumptions that there will be another XElement and it will be the integer element and the value will be an int.  You will need to decide how much you trust the other system is always sending you the XML in this format or if you need to write some defensive code.

```
var age = 23;

var ran = xdoc.Root.Elements("dict")
              .Elements("dict")
              .Elements("dict")
              .Elements("key")
              .Where(x => (string) x == "Age" && (int) x.ElementsAfterSelf.First() > age)
              .Select(x=>x.Parent);
```